# Scaling the font size on a desktop to see how it will look in a phone

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making an in-app message creation tool where you can design the message and send it to a phone.

So when I am designing it, if the set the font size to `16px`, it looks fine on the desktop. But on the phone, the `16px` looks too small.

How to determine that scaling factor by which I should multiply the font size which will enable me to see exactly how it will look on the phone?

I know different phones will have have different scaling factors, but I want to support about 10 popular devices.

So what is the number I'm looking for?

Comment: Just use relative units instead of fixed units.

Comment: Rather than ``px`` use ``em`` or ``rem`` for setting the font size.

Comment: I am using canvas to draw the message, will it work?

Comment: Yes it works with canvas as well. You can try here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_font